# How to import a module in PowerShell from a String variable?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script stored as a variable in memory:

```
$v = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://url/with/module.ps -UseBasicParsing
$s = $v.toString()
```

I'd like to now do something like `Import-Module $s`. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `Import-Module -Name $s`?

Comment: @DavidPostill Unfortunately I'm unable to do this
`PS C:\Users\dir> Import-Module -Name $s
Import-Module : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module -Name $s
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.I 
   mportModuleCommand`

Answer (score 0):

The [New-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module) cmdlet will provide the functionality you need. I've included a commented out offline example to demonstrate usage:

```
$v = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://url/with/module.ps -UseBasicParsing
$s = $v.toString() 
#$s = {function Hello {"Hello!"}} #Offline Example
New-Module -ScriptBlock $s -name GreetingModule | Import-Module
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't quite work with `New-Module`. I found now `Invoke-Expression`, which seems to be doing what I needed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.3